# Why blur is not being applied to dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have styles for header and menu-content for mobile version of website that suppose to have blurred background, but only header gets blurred. Removing blur effect from header results in correct blur on menu-content and vice versa.
Below are CSS, HTML and JS snippets to show dropdown menu.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .header {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 2; 
        background-color: rgba(34, 35, 37, 0.8); 
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    
    .menu-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%; 
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: rgba(34, 35, 37, 0.8);
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
        max-height: 0; 
        z-index: 3;
    }

<body>
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <header class="header">
        <a href="/" class="josefin-sans-header">OMNIA</a>
        <div class="menu-button" onclick="toggleMenu()">
            <div class="menu-line top"></div>
            <div class="menu-line middle"></div>
            <div class="menu-line bottom"></div>
        </div>
        <nav class="menu-content" id="menuContent">
            <div class="menu-item pt-sans-regular-options" id="premium-option">Premium♾️</div>
            <div class="menu-item pt-sans-regular-options">Commands</div>
            <a href="https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=595589012270612508&permissions=8&scope=bot%20applications.commands" class="menu-item pt-sans-regular-options" target="_blank">Invite Bot</a>
            <a href="https://discord.gg/DajNSdYq" class="menu-item pt-sans-regular-options" target="_blank">Help</a>
            <div class="menu-item pt-sans-regular-options">Authorization</div>
        </nav>
    </header>    
    <section class="home geologica-title">
        <div class="content">
            <h2> OMNIA </h2>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="additional-rectangle">
        <div class="server-stats">
            <div class="server-count-text geologica-title" id="server-count-text">Loading...</div>
            <div class="avatars" id="server-avatars">
                <div class="avatar"></div>
                <div class="avatar"></div>
                <div class="avatar"></div>
                <div class="avatar"></div>
                <div class="avatar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="additional-rectangle2">
    </div>
</body>

function toggleMenu() {
    var menuButton = document.querySelector('.menu-button');
    var menuContent = document.getElementById('menuContent');
    menuButton.classList.toggle('x-active');
    
    if (menuContent.style.maxHeight) {
    menuContent.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
    menuContent.style.maxHeight = menuContent.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    }
```

I expected it to blur both header and menu-content, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you turn your code into an actual working snippet? I just copied your code into one and it does not work. You can use the `<>` button when editing your code to get an editor that allows you to add html, css and JS. Make sure that your problem is reproduced in there. For example,  your CSS is invalid in the current coee as the @media is never closed.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to get that cool blur effect on both your header and menu but only one is playing ball, it's usually a hiccup with how the blur layers stack up on each other.

```
.header::after, .menu-content::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
z-index: -1;
```

}

Don't forget to make your .header and .menu-content relative so these pseudo-elements know where to sit.